# Stuck in Facebooks Access Verification hell

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We use the Facebook API in our CMS system to provide a simple **"Import From Facebook"** feature. Clients can import with a single click a Facebook Page post (from their own Facebook Page) to their own website.

To implement this **very simple feature** we had to duck, provide screen recordings, send business registration papers, give login credentials, describe the process from every perspective, crawl and bent.

**Then**

July 17, we recieved the following message:

*"We’re now requiring an admin of your business, [....], to complete access verification. This is a new process that asks for information about how you use the Meta business assets and information of your clients, so we can verify that your business is a Tech Provider."*

**Also in the same message:**

*"This typically takes around 10 minutes to complete and you’ll only need to do this once."*

Since then I filled in the form 7 times, **with serious effort**. But every 5 days it just get rejected **without a clear reason given**, and now (since october 9):

*"The deadline to respond to our request for more information about your response to a question on the access verification form has passed and API calls to certain permissions and features in advanced access for the app, [....], will begin to be blocked."*

**I tried to contact Facebook, but this seems to be impossible**. Some forms (App Review Support) just gives a generic error message: *Something went wrong - An error occurred while creating your question. Please try again later.*, **they do not work**.

1. Does anyone know how to fill in the **"Access Verification - prove you are a Tech Provider form"**, so I will get accepted. I just feel like Facebook has one sided created some new definitions, then decide to enforce them by just trowing forms (with time limits), and clicking on a need-more-info/reject button. Facebook has screen recordings, login credentials, a description of the process, they can see the API endpoints my system is calling, then why do I have to fill in a form **7 times**? Also they are now blocking API calls (resulting in a degradation of the product/service I can deliver to my customers), but on what ground, **I didnt violated any rules**, this is just bad business practice.
2. How to contact Facebook?

Comment: _"The deadline to respond to our request for more information about your response to a question on the access verification form has passed"_ - do you see that request they are talking about anywhere? Did you check your developer email account, to see if anything asking for additional information arrived there?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can see a overview of the forms I filled in, but there is no feedback. The e-mail I recieve every time, only contains: "Thank you for completing access verification for your business, [...]. We need more information about your response to a question so we can verify that your business is a Tech Provider. "

Comment: _"How to contact Facebook?"_ - they don't provide anything simple like just a contact email (of course not, they would be _inundated_ with requests), but you can try and ask in the Facebook Developer's Group. Or maybe file a bug report - that's rather an abuse of the bug report system, but sometimes it at least can get someone to take a look and give _some_ useful feedback.

Comment: Following this - have you been able to get an update from Meta/resolve this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I eventual solved it by "quoting" each "question" (what I guessed Facebook wanted to know (copy paste)) and then answer it individually. For example you have a "Some things to consider" with a couple of suggestion. Instead of following the suggestion I just "quoted" and "answered" (very specific). This made them finally accept me as a tech provider. I guess, I just made it easier for the Facebook employer to process the form, and hit accept instead of reject.

Comment: Ah that makes sense... so it seems the rejection was more the person not processing your original submission rather than your use case being invalid.

When you say you "quoted" and "answered" - what did you quote in your submission? Was it just the permissions-level entries from your app approval questionnaire?

Comment: No only questions relating to the question if you are a "Tech Provider". For example: "Including a business description and examples of your clients", "Add details about how your business will use Platform Data", "Describe how your clients use your product or service", when I quoted each question and suggestion individually and anwsered them in a Q&A format as described above, it got aproved.

Comment: Ah amazing - that makes sense! Thanks for sharing that - currently going through this process and it’s painful haha

Comment: Feeling the pain guys, we are through this same hell right now! Will let you know if the Q&A format works

Comment: Hi guys, can confirm that "quoting" the questions helped! I also tried to be as specific as possibile on both the question regarding my company but also on how the specific app works.

Comment: Great to hear it helped! Tnx for the feedback gfppaste and Lorenzo.