# Stuck in Facebook's Access Verification hell for Tech Provider Business

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We use the Facebook API in our web app to provide a "**publish to Facebook group**" feature directly from the web app. Customers can publish the results they are achieving thanks to our products in our group.

To implement this **very simple feature** we had to duck, provide screen recordings, send business registration papers, give login credentials, describe the process from every perspective, crawl and bent.

Then

on Dec 15, we received the following message:

"We’re now requiring an admin of your business, [....], to complete access verification. This is a new process that asks for information about how you use the Meta business assets and information of your clients, so we can verify that your business is a **Tech Provider**."

Also in the same message:

"This typically takes around 10 minutes to complete and you’ll only need to do this once."

Since then I filled in the form **9 times**, with serious effort. But every 5 days it just get rejected without a clear reason given, and there is no chance to contact a Facebook support.

Does anyone know how to fill in the "Access Verification - prove you are a Tech Provider form", so I will get accepted?

The **actual questions** that they keep asking are:

1. Add details about how your business will use Platform Data (i.e., any info or data you obtain from us) to enable a product or service on behalf of your clients.
2. Describe how your clients use your product or service.

I already tried the solution proposed here:
[Stuck in Facebooks Access Verification hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74039311/stuck-in-facebooks-access-verification-hell)
quoting their questions, but it has been in vain...

The time is running out, in some days Facebook is going to block the API if we don't pass this verification process, but I don't know what else we can try...

**I tried to contact Facebook**, but this seems to be impossible. Some forms (App Review Support) just give a generic error message.

**I tried to post a request of help to the Facebook Developer Group**, but they rejected the request because it's not related to a development issue.
Same when I tried to open a ticket with the **Facebook tech support** for a bug; they answered that it's not a technical issue.

There is no guide from Facebook on how they want this information to be provided.

Comment: Hello, were you able to pass the verification? We are facing exactly the same problem and don't know what to respond those two questions

Comment: Hello, here you can find the ticket that I opened with Meta support.

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/694207002373500/

I think that this was what helped me to solve the issue. I kept on answering the questions about the Tech Provider in the same way, repeatedly, but I don't think that those answers were the problem.

It looks more like a technical problem of the platform, and I managed to go through it  thanks to the ticket above.

Please feel free to ask more question if you need, I was desperate and I understand   what it means to feel powerless against Meta :-)